# Push content from absolute menu with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, menu, submenu, absolute

Hi i need to make a menu with 3 levels.

When you hover the first level sub-menu is displaying under the 1 level inline-block. I will use later flex to make it responsive.

Then it will be the same with the third level.

This is how it is supposed to look like :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEpoK.png)

So now i'm almost good but i can figured out why my menu is bugging.

You can find the jsfiddle here :

https://jsfiddle.net/z1cepma4/

ANy idea how i can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help

---

```js
      var $level1 = $('#nav li');
    var $level2 = $('#nav li ul');
    var $level3 = $('#nav li ul li ul');
    var $pagecontent = $('#fakecontent');
    var hoverTimeout = '';
      var leaveTimeout = '';
    
    
    
    $level1.mouseenter(function() {
     
    
    var $thislevel2 = $(this).children('ul').first();
     
     console.log('hover level 1 val : ' + $(this).text());
     
     
     clearTimeout(leaveTimeout);
         // 1.
         hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
           // 2. Another submenu open
           if( $thislevel2.is(':visible') ) {
           console.log('level 2 visible');
             // if new hovered li has megamenu, hide old menu and show the new, otherwise slide everything back up
             if( $thislevel2.length ) {
               // stop any other hoverTimeouts triggered through guick back-and-forth hovering
               clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); 
               $thislevel2.filter(':visible').stop(true, true).hide();
               $thislevel2.stop(true, true).show();
               
               console.log('level 2 - parti 1');
             } else {
               $thislevel2.filter(':visible').stop(true, true).slideUp(500);
               $pagecontent.stop(true, true).animate({ paddingTop: '0'}, 500);
                  console.log('level 2 - parti 2');
             }
           } else {
            
             console.log('level 2 not visible');
             if( $thislevel2.length ) {
            
            
               // stop any other hoverTimeouts triggered through guick back-and-forth hovering
               clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); 
               $thislevel2.stop(true, true).show();
               
            
               /* 16.5em is the set height of the megamenu + negative margin of nav ul */
               $pagecontent.stop(true, true).animate({ marginTop: '10em'}, 500);
             }
           }
         }, 200);
     }); //$level1 mouseenter
       
      $level1.mouseleave(function() {
       clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
       leaveTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
         if( $level2.is(':visible') ) {
           $level2.filter(':visible').stop(true, true).slideUp(500);
           $pagecontent.stop(true, true).animate({ marginTop: '0'}, 500);
         }
       }, 200);
     });
```

```css
   #fakeheader,
#fakecontent{
  width:100%;
   height:150px;
  background:red;
  position:relative
  }
#nav {position: relative;}
#nav li {
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  color:red;
 color:#FFF;
 opacity:1;
}

/* Targeting the first level menu */
#nav {  
   
    min-width:850px;
    background:#fff;
    display: block;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
}
#nav > li > a {
  color:#000;
}


/* Targeting the second level menu */
#nav li ul {
    color: #333;
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
}
#nav li ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 8px 0 10px;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
    color:red;
    opacity:1;
}

#nav li ul li:hover>a{color:red;}

/* Third level menu */
#nav li ul li ul{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
}
ul.child {
background-color:#FFF;  
}
/* A class of current will be added via jQuery */
#nav li.current > a {
    color:red;
    float:left;
}

/*
#nav li:hover > ul.child {
    left:0;
    top:34px;
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
}
#nav li:hover > ul.grandchild  {
    display:block;
}*/
#nav > li:hover > a{color:red;}
#nav > li > a > li:hover > a{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fakeheader">Header
</div>
<div id="#menu-categories">

<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Quoi manger/Ou dormir...</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#">Associations</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">Associations 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Associations 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Associations 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Autre</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">Autre 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Autre 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Autre 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Quoi faire...</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#">Associations</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">Culturelle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Culturelle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Culturelle</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Associations</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">Culturelle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Culturelle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Culturelle</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
   
</ul>
</div>
<div id="fakecontent">
Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of toggle  and animate:

```
$('#nav').addClass('active');

$('#nav li').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('> ul').toggleClass('active');
  var visible = $('#menu-categories').find('ul.active').length;
  $('#menu-categories').animate({
    'height': visible * 35
  }, {
    queue: false
  });
  $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle();

})
```

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/rw6L4nqq/1/

Comment: Hi thanks but no it's is not working it has to be done with jquery to push the content. It's the only way to do it since it is absolute positioning.

Comment: Thanks it's almost that i want to have only the animation to open the submenu if i switch to a different category i just want to use show and hide and if i leave the menu slideUp is it possible? thanks a lot for your help

Comment: its possible but will need a lot more coding , it will be alot easier to refactor your html to remove the absolute position

Comment: you need to move your ul outside any other ul

Comment: yes but it's not going to work for responsive menu i need it inside is parent when it's on mobile

Comment: mmm you are right but how can i make it inside parent on mobile ?

Comment: append the ul's using jquery

Comment: can you help me with an exemple? that will be so nice because here the height is fixed but the ul can contain multiple row i'm lost :( since i's going to be responsive